# Authentication with Google (to get rtmp URL) without using WebView in a Xamarin Project?

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, google-signin, chrome-custom-tabs, xamarin.auth

I'm trying to develop a Xamarin project which is able to stream on YouTube.
I want to get the rtmp URL from the user account.
But, recently Google has disabled webviews to authorize apps to get accesstoken and other user data.

I have tried to use Xamarin Auth but unfortunately, it actually uses a webview.
(getUI() is returning a webview).

So I'm asking if someone knows how to authenticate a user with Google without webviews?

I have also tried using custom tabs but I can't get the URL to get the access token because the NavigationEvent is not fired when a new page is loaded.

Comment: Xamarin.Auth has added Chrome CustomTabs support in the latest versions, but beware, quote from the readme: **'unfinished/untested/undocumented API`** https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/portable-bait-and-switch#v1323

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have also tried this branch unfortunatly i don't know how to install nuget that are not from the nuget manager
Can you tell me how to do that ? If I have to compile the nupkg or maybe I can download it somewhere already compiled.

Comment: Please mention in the question - Which platform are you targeting at? Xamarin.Auth 1.4.1 and subsequent alpha releases has good support for both Forms and Native.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Auth 1.4.x supports Custom Tabs and SafariViewController, but no Xamarin.Forms support what most of the users want.
Xamarin.Forms support is in the 1.5.0-alpha soon to be released.

Samples extracted from the repo:

https://github.com/moljac/Xamarin.Auth.Samples.NugetReferences

Try ComicBook (Xamarin.Forms) or Providers (Traditional/Standard).

Nuget packages tuning can be problematic, just bump versions to the highest.